# Change flag queue tooltip

Tags: bug, flags, top-bar, tooltips

The tooltip of the flag queue in the top-bar is:

[image: flag tooltip]

But we can't handle moderator flags - only "normal" flags. Maybe it should better be

> we have flagged posts, perhaps you can help

Comment: That's not related to review, it's a totally different thing. It appears in the same place it used to appear in the old top bar, as far as I remember.